# simple form with associations through two attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a rails project, where model `textbook` has many `book` models. The `textbook` model has several attributes, two of them are `publisher` and `branch`. In the Add New page for `book`, I need to specify the `publisher` and `branch` for the book based on the existing publishers and the corresponding branches for that publisher. Then after selecting them, the association will be completed and the corresponding `textbook` record will be known for that `book`. I have not defined `publisher` and `branch` attributes for `book`, because I want to retrieve them from the associated `textbook`, whenever needed. This way, if later there is any change in the associated `textbook`, it will automatically be updated for the `book`.

I am using `simple_form`. My problem is that in the form, I don't know how to use
`= f.input`

to specify the `publisher` and `branch` for `book`, and then specify the corresponding `textbook` record. If it was just one attribute, I could use

`= f.association :textbook`

but because I need to specify two attributes separately, I don't know how to do that.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what *publisher* and *branch* attributes you can chooose from as options to use as values, but if your form needs to select from a set of options, you can simply call those data values as *collections* within the form to specify what values can be used for any given attribute on the textbook record.   E.g.:

```
= simple_form_for :textbook do |f|
  = f.input :publisher, collection: Publisher.all, as: :select #collection can be any values
  = f.input :branch, as: :text #if user can manually type in a branch name

  = f.simple_fields_for :book do |b| #this is a nested form field
    = b.input :name #instead of :name, use the name of attributes you have for this table/model
```

If your Branch and Publisher value options were an arrays of values, you could call a collection like above, and expand the form to also have nested fields for editing information about the Book table itself by referencing the associated model with `simple_fields_for`, then in your `Textbook` adding `accept_nested_attributes_for` so that the nested `Book` model can be updated by the `Textbook` model within this form submission:

*book.rb:*

```
class Textbook < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :books #add this
end
```

If you are using Rails 4, also watch out for strong parameters when you do this -- make sure to explicitly define the strong parameters within your controllers when updating.

Let me know if this helps.  Also make sure to closely check simple_form's documentation. https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that I don't want to have publisher and branch attributes in `book`.  so I can't use `f.input`. publisher and branch are defined for `textbook` model. Also since the `book` form is on different page, I can't use `f.simple_fields_for` in its form. In fact in the form for `book`, I need to chose a `publisher` and a `branch` of that publisher, then based on that specify the `textbook_id` that the `book` belongs to.